# javax.mail: Sending without authentication hangs inside Transport.send()

Tags: authentication, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send error reports from an application using a local send-only Postfix server. The server works fine (I have tested it using both telnet and mail) but I can't get the code below to work:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host",host);                   // "localhost"
props.put("mail.smtp.port",port);                   // "25"
props.put("mail.smtp.auth",auth);                   // false
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable",tls);         // false
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable",ssl);              // false
props.put("mail.smtp.sendpartial",true);

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
msg.setSubject(subject);
msg.setContent(content,"text/plain");

Transport.send(msg);
```

I have traced it up to the final call to send(), and it just hangs at that point -- it never returns from the call.

If I set "mail.smtp.auth" to true and replace the call to Transport.send() with this code:

```
Transport transport = s.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect(host,Integer.parseInt(port,10),"foo","bar");
transport.sendMessage(msg,msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
transport.close();
```

then it hangs inside the call to connect(). The same as true if I set "mail.smtp.auth" to false and set the username and password to null in the call to connect().

In /var/log/mail.log I see this:

```
connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
```

and after I kill the hung process:

```
lost connection after CONNECT from localhost[127.0.0.1]
disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] commands=0/0
```

Can anyone see what I've done wrong here?

Comment: Replace the call Session.getDefaultInstance with Session.getInstance and re-test.

Comment: Makes no difference. Because it hangs rather than throwing an exception, I assume that it is waiting for the mailserver to respond to the connection... so I'm going to try and find out what is passing back and forth between the application and the mail server.

Comment: [Turn on session debugging](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/FAQ.html#debug) and post the output.  You should be able to see where it is hanging.  The FAQ also include information on SSL debugging and even how to test with other programs.  Try that and update your question with the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the user "postfix" was being blocked by iptables. Adding an ACCEPT rule for postfix solved the problem.